# Column values into floats when trying to drop rows from a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe

```
   A  B     C
0  1  2  None
1  1  3   XYZ
2  5  4   abc
```

I am trying to remove all rows based on groupby COl :A, if any of the value is None, remove that entire group

Expected output

```
   A  B    C
0  5  4  abc
```

THis is what i am trying to do

```
import pandas as pd

# Create the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [1, 1, 5],
    'B': [2, 3, 4],
    'C': [None, 'XYZ', 'abc']
})
print(df)
# Group by column A and drop any rows with null values
df = df.groupby('A').apply(lambda x: x.dropna() if x.notnull().all().all() else pd.DataFrame())

# Reset the index of the resulting dataframe
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

# Print the resulting dataframe
print(df)
```

But what i am getting is this :

```
     A    B    C
0  5.0  4.0  abc
```

Why are the values getting converted into float? I dont want that to happen

Comment: Not entirely sure why you're getting float values, but usually pandas converts to float if there are/could be any "missing" values that it can encode as NaN. In any case, what about using a `GroupBy.filter`? `df.groupby("A").filter(lambda x: x.notna().all(axis=None))`

Comment: The `pd.DataFrame()` is what messes up the data type.

Comment: but the first `print(df)` works fine and shows the correct data type, well atleast without the `.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Quang Hoang mentioned in the comments, the issue is with your apply code. Why not try using `groupby` and `transform` to create a mask in this fashion:

```
df[df['C'].notna().groupby(df['A']).transform('all')]

   A  B    C
2  5  4  abc
```

You can call `.reset_index` on the result if needed.

---

Another similar approach:

```
df[df.set_index('A')['C'].notna().groupby(level=0).transform('all')]
```

This can generalize to multiple columns if you need to check nullity for all:

```
df[df.set_index('A').notna().all(axis=1).groupby(level=0).transform('all')]

   A  B    C
2  5  4  abc
```